# get an Erro, methode isn`t allowed

Tags: html, node.js, forms, post, sqlite

This is the error I get: `HTTP-Fehler 405.0 - Method Not Allowed`

I try to send from my `HTML>FROM/Action:test.js>test.js` to get it in my sqlite3 Database, but I don't get it. What is going wrong?

Here my HTML code:

```html
<form action="test.js" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="Gehalt" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Senden">
</form>
```

My `test.js` is in the same folder!

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(bodyParser());
let Gehalt
console.log("hier soll");
app.post('test.js', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    //var url = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    //Gehalt = req.body.url
});
```

Comment: You are sending a POST request to an endpoint that is actually a static file. That won't work.

Comment: oki, what will work?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: I will try it. I hope i will get this. Thanks alot men =)

Comment: i don't know it doesn't work. First problem html Form send, to nothing i get the error 405.0.                              Problem 2.) test.js get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `.js` extension

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="Gehalt" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Senden">
</form>
```

```
app.post('/test', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  //var url = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  //Gehalt = req.body.url
});
```